# Netbeans 8 and NodeJS plugin - erroneous partial install?

Tags: node.js, netbeans

I install NodeJS plugin for Netbeans 8 (node.js for Windows installed before).
I see only tab "Node.js" in Other options with only 2 parameters: default run command and default kill command. No other parameters. No project type "Node.js". Almost nothing.
nb\var\log\messages doesn't contain error for NodeJS plugin.
What's wrong?

Comment: Uninstall - install NodeJS - doesn't affect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem reproduced for NodeJS plugin 2.2 included into Netbeans update center.
But NodeJS plugin 2.28 downloaded from [Tim Boudreau's NetBeans Update Center](http://timboudreau.com/modules) works well.
Please do not use internal Netbeans' list of modules at least for NodeJS